# Lodash function to modify each element in array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following array:

```
let array = [ "c0709f80b718", "c47b86124fde" ];
```

What is the fastest lodash function to be able to add the ":" in eacch element of the array to convert to a mac address format.

Expected output should be:

```
let array = [ "c0:70:9f:80:b7:18", "c4:7b:86:12:4f:de" ];
```

Comment: `_.map` or native `array.map`. Use like `array.map(item => \`new item: ${item}\`)`

Comment: _What ... is the fastest?_ -> https://jsperf.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` to iterate the array, and a RegExp with `String.match()` to split each string, and then join it with `:`.

```js
const array = [ "c0709f80b718", "c47b86124fde" ];

const result = array.map(str => str.match(/.{2}/g).join(':'))

console.log(result)
```

As @Akrion suggested, with lodash you can use `_.words` with the same RegExp pattern to split the string:

```js
const array = [ "c0709f80b718", "c47b86124fde" ]

const result = _.map(array, str => _.words(str, /.{2}/g).join(':'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Clever strategy using `.match`. Lovely one.

Comment: Correct answer, however not the answer the OP is looking for. "What is the fastest lodash function". But I think this is just as good.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Despite your point is absolutely true, it's still worth to note that this can be accomplished with vanilla js and that the lodash signature would be the exact same, due to the nature of how map is implement in lodash as well: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map

Comment: You could use `_.words(str, /.{2}/g)` to be more in the context of lodash or as an optional lodash only answer.